# Delete last record of table WordPress

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am trying to delete the last record of a mySQL table using WordPress `$wpdb`. Iv'e tried this:

```
global $wpdb;

$wpdb->delete('claps',array('orderby' => 'id desc limit 1'));
```

But it doesn't work. The `$wpdb` variable is working well because I have done insert queries before this, so the problem is in the delete query. Can someone show me how is this done in WordPress.
Thank you.

Comment: you get any errors ?  put this after the delete and check it -  if( ! empty($wpdb2->error) )
 wp_die( $wpdb2->error );

Comment: No, there aren't any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried doing this and it worked.

```
global $wpdb;

$results = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM claps ORDER BY id DESC limit 1');

$id = $results[0]->id;

$wpdb->delete('claps',array('id' => $id));

wp_die();
```

Answer (score 2):

You have probably a mistake in your array. The second parameter of the method `delete()` should be about the **WHERE** in your SQL. More info you may find here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/delete/#parameters

> **$where**
>
> (array) (Required) A named array of WHERE clauses (in column =>
> value pairs). Multiple clauses will be joined with ANDs. Both $where
> columns and $where values should be "raw". Sending a null value will
> create an IS NULL comparison - the corresponding format will be
> ignored in this case.

Answer (score 0):

```
$last_insert_id = $wpdb->insert_id;
$table = 'eLearning_progress';
$wpdb->delete( $table, array( 'ID' => $last_insert_id ) );
```